# how to find farthest neighbors in Euclidean space?

Tags: search, data-structures, computational-geometry

Given a set P of n points in 2D, for any point x in P, what is the fastest way to find out the farthest neighbor of x? By farthest neighbor, we mean a point in P which has the maximum Euclidean distance to x.

Comment: Depends on how the points are given. If you just have an unordered list, then iterating over the list is the fastest way.

Comment: @JFMeier I can do any preprocessing of the data if it helps to find the farthest neighbor in less than O(n) time. For the nearest neighbor, we can build a kd-tree and find the nearest neighbor in logN time. I am looking for something like that.

Comment: You can find a lower bound in constant time, by observing the 4 points of your data set which have the minimal/maximal value for their 1st/2nd coordinate. That will allow you to go though lists of points ordered by their 1st/2nd coordinates more quickly by discarding entire parts.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the current standard kNN search algorithm for various trees (R-Trees, quadtrees, kd-trees) was developed by:

> G. R. Hjaltason and H. Samet., "Distance browsing in spatial
>   databases.", ACM TODS 24(2):265--318. 1999

See [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.386.8193&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  It traverses the tree based on a priority queue of nearest nodes/entries. **One key insight is that the algorithm also works for farthest neighbor search**.

The basic algorithm uses a priority queue. The queue can contain tree nodes as well as data entries, all sorted by their distance to your search point.
As initial step it adds the root node to the priority queue. Then repeat the following until `k` entries have been found:

1. Take the first element from the queue. If it is an entry, return it. If it is a node, add all elements in the node to the priority queue.
2. Repeat 1.

The paper describes an implementation for R-Trees, but they claim it can be applied to most tree-like structures. I have implemented the **nearest** neighbor version myself for [R-Trees](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/tree/master/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/rtree) and [PH-Trees](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree) (a special type of quadtree), both in Java. I think I know how to do it efficiently for KD-Trees but I believe it is somewhat complicated.

Comment: The farthest point from anything is on the convex hull, so the first thing to do is to generate the convex hull and throw away everything else.  Then put the hull points into a KD tree and do this search.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes that would certainly work, but that would be a different solution. Maybe it's worth if you put this at your own answer?
Also, creating a convex hull is not for free, but in 2D it may well lead to a cheaper solution overall.